# multiprocessing.Pool behavior when called multiple time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a very simple question based on my observation:

Let's consider the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x,y):
    # Do heavy stuff

N = 8
param_to_test = [(x,y) for x in range(1000) for y in range(1000)]
with mp.Pool(processes = N) as p:
    p.starmap(f, param_to_test)

param_to_test = [(x,y) for x in range(1000, 2000) for y in range(1000, 2000)]
with mp.Pool(processes = N) as p:
    p.starmap(f, param_to_test)

param_to_test = [(x,y) for x in range(2000, 3000) for y in range(2000, 3000)]
with mp.Pool(processes = N) as p:
    p.starmap(f, param_to_test)
```

Let's also assume that the duration of each iteration is constant. I observe that if I do multiple calls of `mp.Pool()` in my main program, the last ones are (seems) far slower than the first one.

In my actual program, before each call of the `with mp.Pool()`, param_to_test is computed based on what the previous one computed.
I know that spawning process is actually not fast in python, and there is probably a better way to code this than spawning 3 times (or more...) the same `Pool()` of workers. However, this duration is negligible in my case.

***My question is:*** Is Python correctly closing the `Pool()` everytime and isn't there any issues I'm unaware of in the behavior of the `Pool()` that could explain the progressive slowing down of the computation?

Thanks :)

Comment: "Let's also assume that the duration of each iteration is constant." If you replace `#do heavy stuff` with `return x + y`, do you see the same degradation in performance?

Comment: @TomDalton I'm not going to go on that part. My actual function is actually doing some huge computation which can last from 10 s to 10 minutes. For a few of them, I even get a RAM consumption of 80 Gb. i.e. This is a HUGE assumption, completely wrong. However, I've noticed that if I start with lighter stuff on the 3 / 4 first call of `mp.Pool()` (about 2 hours each) and then start the call on an input needing more computation (1 week), it is slower than if I stop the program and restart it only on the last `Pool()` which thus last less than 1 week.

Comment: Example: In 5 days I generated 1K1 files. I've restarted only the last `Pool()` today, I've generated 900 files in 5 hours. I didn't generate the same file (i.e. I skipped the input already computed). But even with this, and even if each file generation takes a different unique amount of time, I should not observe such a huge difference between the 1K1 first inputs and the 900 following.

Comment: If your question is "Do successive calls to Pool get slower", you can test this for yourself with the code above, replacing `#do heavy stuff` with something like `return x + y`. If your question is " Is Python correctly closing the Pool() everytime?" you could check for yourself this by inspecting the running processes on your system. If your question is "can someone explain the progressive slowing down of the computation?" then I think there isn't enough detail (specifically, exactly what `f` is doing) to be able to answer this.

Comment: @TomDalton First thanks for the reply. So true I could test this, and I probably will. For the part inspecting the running processes, I did some time, I really don't always understand what it is doing because the iteration of the function f are really different one from the other. Thus the behavior is quite funny (RAM goes up, some processes at 0% for some time, some at 7% CPUs...). I'm not giving more detail, because I don't see a point in giving 800+ lines of code to review. The goal was to get a feeling of what was happening based on other people experiences with multiprocessing.

Comment: Sure thing. I suspect the issue relates to whatever your function `f` is actually doing.

Comment: @TomDalton That's what I would be saying too if I didn't computed in 6 hours more inputs than in the 5 previous days (1K2 vs 1K1). The function f computation is long, and each input will have a different duration, but the difference is just to huge here. And the only difference between today and before is that I restarted the program only on the last `Pool()`. Thus the question on the multiple Pool calling behavior...

Comment: Does `f` return anything to your main process?

Comment: @TomDalton No just saving a .pkl file to disk (directly in the function).

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark, but if all your `f` invocations take 10s or more to run, and potentially use large amounts of memory, you might want to consider using `maxtasksperchild=1` when creating your [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) to ensure that any memory leak issues in `f` don't impact the next one.

Comment: In the above case you should probably also set `chunksize=1` when calling starmap.

Comment: @TomDalton Really interested by this. Could you detail a bit what those 2 parameters are and do? `maxtasksperchild=1` I assumed that each worker (process) gets one new task every time it finished the one it was doing. Without this parameter, can they actually have 2+ tasks running at the same time ? i.e. 2 calls of the function `f()` simultaneously on the same worker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171557/discussion-between-tom-dalton-and-mathieu).